# routing urls not correctly django 1.8

Tags: django, routes

Help! I have a simple problem.

I made links in my templates, like this:

```
<a href="students">students</a>
```

When i go to alumni.html and i click on the link directing to students.html, it directs to **alumni**/students

but i want to click and see /students.

I dont understand why its routing to alumni/students instead.

I only changed one aspect of settings.py into: 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^students/$', 'assignments.views.students', name='students'),
    url(r'^alumni/$', 'assignments.views.alumni', name='alumni'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def students(request):
    return render(request, "students.html", {})

def alumni(request):
    return render(request, "alumni.html", {})
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the url in the template to this

```
<a href="{% url 'students' %}">students</a>
```

Comment: That worked! I waisted 4 hours of my live before i dared to ask the question, i should have asked earlier. Thank you so much Exprator!